# Use of the word "translucent " other than the literal meaning

Tags: word-usage

How can I use the word Translucent other than its literal meaning ?
For example, can I say - "Your policies are translucent" instead of  "Your policies are available for all to view but not clear to understand" ?

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative word or do you want to know about the usage of the word in a non-scientific context? Your tags, title and question body do not seem to match.

Comment: I have changed the tag.

Comment: I think you mean "literal meaning" rather than "scientific meaning".  Translucency, like transparency or opacity, is not intrinsically scientific.

Comment: Thanks Max, I updated the question according to your suggestion.

Comment: The term is used metaphorically at times.  It's not as well recognized as "transparent" and "opaque" in this sense, however.

Comment: Why would anyone use *translucent* in the context of policies, when *transparent* is not only stronger, but also more understandable: when is a policy translucent but not transparent?

Comment: I guess you could if you said something like "Your policies are not transparent, they're translucent." But without setting the two in opposition to each other, people would probably just think you mixed up translucent with transparent.

Comment: @DavidHandelman - The OP effectively explains the figurative meaning of *translucent* in his question, but then your comment effectively demonstrates how it might be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

You can but without knowing the context, it would be very confusing unless you literally said "Your policies are translucent; they are available for all to view but not clear to understand"